# Proof about isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Who has clues about this problem? It is so difficult for me. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: See [this](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Foster06728003.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group of orientation-preserving symmetries of a dodecahedron.

Hints:

1. Try to show that $|G|=60$, so it is sufficient to show that $A_5$ is a subgroup of $G$.
2. $\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^5=1\rangle$ is a presentation for $A_5$, so see if you can find elements of $G$ of orders $2$ and $3$ such that their product has order $5$.  This will probably involve staring at a picture of a dodecahedron for a few minutes.  (Hint for the hint: the element of order three can be taken to be the cyclic permutation of three faces meeting at a vertex).